# PhoneGap 2.9.0 -- Can't get app to access camera

Tags: cordova

I've exhausted every resource I can find on this, and nothing has helped. As far as I can tell, there's something wrong with this line:

```js
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-x.x.x.js"></script>
```

I copied the example from the documentation on camera use 
( http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.9.0/cordova_camera_camera.md.html ) and my PhoneGap is version 2.9.0. The issue I seem to be having is that I don't actually have the cordova-2.9.0.js file. Why is that? Where is it?

Trying to run my code now throws

> "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getPicture' of undefined at file:///android_asset/www/test.html:12"

I've included a lot of permissions in my config.xml file out of desperation for something to work:

```xml
<plugin name="Camera" value="org.apache.cordova.CameraLauncher" />
<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/device" />
<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/camera"/>
<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/file"/>
<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/media"/>
<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/network"/>
```

I've been at this for hours and I would really appreciate any help I can get.

EDIT: I'm working on Android and I've also tried "cordova.js" instead of "cordova-x.x.x.js" with the same results

EDIT: I reinstalled PhoneGap with the latest version. I have a "cordova.js" and a "phonegap.js" and they're exactly the same. I left my reference line thing as "cordova.js" and I'm still getting the Uncaught TypeError, but now it's saying `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'PictureSourceType' of undefined` and `...Cannot read property 'PNG' of undefined.` I put the permissions back in the config.xml file and this:

```xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

in the AndroidManifest. Can anyone help? Why am I getting this error?

Comment: What is the name of your cordova JS file? Is it just cordova.js? Have you placed that file inside any folder?

Comment: It's just cordova.js and I haven't moved it.

Comment: I think ur missing Cordova file reference in your html....phonegap has removed version named for cordova file for easy migration

Comment: Isn't that "<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out.

The problem was that I needed to install the plugins using the command line interface
( http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-line%20Interface )

Works, now!