# cordova 3.3.0 - camera not launching

Tags: cordova, android-camera, phonegap-plugins, cordova-3

I ended up searching everywhere with the errors on launching camera on cordova version 3.3.0 - with no success. I did the following as per the [documentation](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.3.0/cordova_camera_camera.md.html#Camera)

1. Added plugin to the project (cordova ver 3.3.0)
2. Cross-verified the config.xml and the manifest.xml and observed that the said elements are already there.

I still get errors like-

1. Uncaugtht TypeError: Cannot read property 'DATA_URL' of undefined.

I am vexed of searching for this error. Kindly help me. I need this working very soon :(

I got some help from SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17974627/phonegap-2-9-0-cant-get-app-to-access-camera).

What else should I do to get access to the camera?

Comment: do you have the cordova.js linked in your index? did you wait for the device ready event before trying to call the camera?

Comment: @jcesar - yes, I have the cordova file linked and am able to see the device ready confirmation in the console.log.

Comment: whats ur cordova.js version is dat also pointing version 3.3 ?

Comment: yes Divesh Salian.. the Cordova version is 3.3.0. I have created this project through Node.JS (as per instructions given on the phonegap official site - CLI instructions)

Comment: did you do a "cordova prepare android" after adding the plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had the same problem. I tried jcesar's suggestion, "did you do a "cordova prepare android" after adding the plugin?" and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

For Cordova 3.3.0,
you need to add the plugin using CLI,

```
 $ phonegap local plugin add org.apache.cordova.camera
 $ phonegap local plugin add org.apache.cordova.media-capture
```

Have you done this?